# React - Advice for testing a NavBar Component

Tags: reactjs, testing, enzyme

I am a new user trying to understand testing of React components. I am using Enzyme with Jest in a Typescript environment.

One of the components that I am trying to test is a NavBar component, implemented using material-ui buttons.

```js
const NavBarLinks = (): JSX.Element => (
  <>
    <Button
      color="inherit"
      component={NavLink}
      activeClassName={navbar.highlighted}
      to="/about"
    >
      About
    </Button>
    <Button
      activeClassName={navbar.highlighted}
      color="inherit"
      component={NavLink}
      to="/courses"
    >
      Courses
    </Button>
    <Button
      activeClassName={navbar.highlighted}
      color="inherit"
      component={NavLink}
      exact={true}
      to="/"
    >
      Home
    </Button>
  </>
);
```

I have written a snapshot test to test that the component renders buttons with expected links and properties etc.

Is there a need to also test that the navbar component changes the route when a button has been clicked? I have started writing a test for this functionality [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59554819/how-to-test-a-route-change-in-a-navbar-component-with-jest-and-enzyme-in-a-types).

Is it the view that the NavLink component provided by `react-router` already has tests for this functionality. Subsequently, it is unnecessary to write tests for changing each route on the navbar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a great question and it boils down to testing philosophies. There are multiple types of tests: unit testing, end to end testing, etc.

If you're testing a *component*, you're unit testing it. Basically you're testing that it behaves as it should in somewhat isolation. For this, a snapshot test is good, and you can double down by testing the specific values it has, such as the `url` each Button has.

[React Testing Library[(https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library) makes this very easy and I'd actually recommend using it vs Enzyme.

If you'd like to test whether the navbar renders what it's supposed to render, it becomes an `end to end test`.

Comment: Many thanks for response :) Thanks for link to React Testing Library. So, unit tests would check component properties etc.  and are best done using snapshots. Functionality  such as routes, connecting to redux store etc. and full rendering would be end to end test examples....

Comment: Snapshots aren't enough for unit testing complex components. Snapshot + testing for specific values (such as the url and text of your Button) are great ways to have solid tests.

You can still unit test redux stores, functions, etc, but if you want to test across pages that's best done with end to end. It's hard to simplify testing in a comment tho, search for some articles. Kend C Doods is fantastic at this.

Comment: @anon_dcs3spp So should the e2e test exist in the Navbar component or outside it?

Comment: @ReturnOfTheMac For e2e tests I used [cypress](https://www.cypress.io/). This allowed me to load a browser instance and a page, then test that each navbar link on that page moves to the expected route...